# Why doesn't this jQuery selector work?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

`$('del, .set-ui-icon-15x41-new:has(:parent+div:has(ins))').toggle(500);`

Basically I'm looking to toggle all `del` tags, and `span`s which have the class name of 'set-ui-icon-15x41-new' that have a parent which contains a child div that has an `ins` tag.

To simplify; this doesn't work either:

`$('.set-ui-icon-15x41-new:parent')`

But this does...

`$('.set-ui-icon-15x41-new').parent()`

So how can I get the `:parent` selector to work?

Comment: Can you post your mark-up? And/or a live [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/rocketbob/bq4Au/2

Answer (score 5):

[:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) will select elements that are parents, not the parent of the element.

Possible solution:

```
$(':has(ins) > .set-ui-icon-15x41-new')
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bq4Au/

Updated demo after comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/bq4Au/5/

Comment: I would try and put an alternative solution, but I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, removed it since it didn't work anyway. It would select everything up the tree.

Comment: I put another possible solution up.

Comment: I've updated the markup so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish better. http://jsfiddle.net/rocketbob/bq4Au/2/

Comment: This does what I want, but I'd like a cleaner approach: $('.set-ui-icon-15x41-new').parent().next().has('ins').prev().find('.set-ui-icon-15x41-new').toggle();

Comment: That doesn't seem to match what you stated above. So you want to run your code if the next item after the parent has an 'ins' tag? Is the markup provided structurally accurate to your scenario?

Comment: Sometimes you are doing something that is so complicated that there is only so much you can reduce what you need to do. I think a filter is probably the least confusing. I updated the example above.